# JavaFx: make progressbar indeterminate

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ProgressBar in javafx fxml file. How can I make it indeterminate in controller?

**EDIT 1**
In javafx scenebuilder you can make a progressbar indeterminate via checkbox. So, I want to do it in controller. By other words, how can I do it via code?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha See the edit1.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Assumption/Solution

As you do not provide enough code, like you normally should [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I will assume you need the following controller code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

  @FXML
  private ProgressBar bar;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    bar.setProgress(ProgressBar.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
  }

}
```

This simply sets the Progress to -1.